# On $\zeta(s)=h^2(s)$ when we presume that the Riemann zeta function has no zeros for $\Re s>\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-zeta, analytic-functions

By specialization of a theorem from complex analysis, one has that on assumption that the **Riemann zeta function** $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros with $\Re s>\frac{1}{2}$, then **there exists an analytic function** $h$ defined on $\Re s>\frac{1}{2}$ such that $\zeta=h^2$.

I've computed and did a construction with the purpose to understand and learn more about complex analysis techniques.

> **Question 1.** Can you say if any of the following claims are wrongs or there are mistakes?
>
> 1) One has that  $$\zeta'(s)=2\zeta(s)\cdot\frac{h'(s)}{h(s)}$$ for  $\Re s>\frac{1}{2}$, and it is not necessary declare a special branch of $h^2$ to do previous computation.
>
> 2) It is possible justify for $\Re s>\frac{1}{2}$
>   $$(h(s))^2-2h(s)h'(s)=\frac{1}{s-1} \left(  \frac{2s-1}{s-1} \right)-s^2\int_1^\infty\frac{(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)\log x}{x^{s+1}}dx,$$
>   and from here it is possible compute the limit as $s\to\frac{1}{2}^{+}$ as $\zeta(\frac{1}{2})-\frac{1}{2}\zeta'(\frac{1}{2})-1$.

Let a disk $\mathcal{D}$ centered in the abscissa $b$ and ordinate $t$ that is the ordinate of a non-trivial zero $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function ( a zero with $\Im \rho>0$ and $\sigma=\Re \rho=\frac{1}{2}$), radius $r=\overrightarrow{ab}$, where $\frac{1}{2}<a<b$ and $\overrightarrow{\sigma a}=\epsilon$ thus with we take $\epsilon>0$. We consider $\xi$ as the complex number $\frac{a+b}{2}+it$, and the rectangle $\mathcal{R}$ whose vertices are $a-irt,b-irt,b+irt$ and $a+irt$.

Now we consider the sequence of previous items defined as before where $\mathcal{D}'$ will be the disk centered in the abscissa $b':=a-\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and ordinate $t'$ that is the ordinate of the following non-trivial zero when the imaginary part increases, and radius $r'=\overrightarrow{a'b'}$, ... For this **new  iterated denoted by the prime** $'$, I've computed using the **Cauchy's formula**
$$\zeta(\xi')=h(\xi')^2=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \left( \int_{\partial \mathcal{D}'} \frac{h(z)}{z-{\xi'}}dz\right). $$ 
On the other hand, using the **Hadamard three-lines theorem** applied to the strip $a'<b'$ we can deduce that $\log M$ is convex, where $$M(x):=\sup_{y} \left| h(x+iy) \right|,$$
and we are defining now (**update** to makes sense the **Question 2.**, I believe that now has the meaning that I wanted)
$$\hat{M}(x):=\sup_{-\sqrt{(r')^2-(x')^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{(r')^2-(x')^2}} \left| h(x+iy) \right|$$

> **Question 2.** I am agree that previous is an hypothetical approach, and perhaps we can not do computations: it is possible a comparison of sizes between $ \left| \zeta(\xi') \right| $ and $(\hat{M}(\Re\xi'))^2$ (thus one has $\Re \xi'$ near to $\frac{1}{2}$)? If previous computations are no feasibles or are non- comparable quantities, explain us.

**Thanks in advance.** If some part of previous isn't well-possed, please add a comment, and I can improve my post or delete that part, while it is possible.

Comment: I did an **update**, ask me if it is conffused, I mean the comparison between values relatively larges on the chord through the abscissa $\Re\xi'$ and low values on arcs measured by Cauchy integral.

Comment: Welcome @user1952009 I am sorry, very thanks much for your patience and the patience of all users, I am agree with you. I understand your words, because mathematics are rigor and clarity. I hope if there are contributions for my question, in another case I think what can I do with this post, and I try modify my actitude in next posts.

Comment: lol... why don't you write the steps you are considering for arriving at your formulas ?

Comment: by the way, $\frac{1}{s-1}$ is meromorphic with a simple pole at $s=1$, as $\zeta(s)$. is there an analytic/meromorphic function $h(s)$ such that $\frac{1}{s-1} = h(s)^2$ ?

Comment: I know that my post have deficiences, then I think if  that it is also very extensive, may seem less attractive to read, thanks @user1952009

Comment: (and searching for a function $h$ such that $f(s) = h(s)^2$ is  not so different as searching for a function $g$ such that $f(s) = e^{g(s)}$ (i.e. $g(s) = \ln f(s)$) )

Comment: This last I know (I say the compuations involving the exponential). With respect the previous question, I believe that there is no an analytic/meromorphic function satisfying your relationship @user1952009

Comment: and how do you solve this problem, that $\frac{1}{s-1}$ has no square root (nor logarithm) in the case of $\zeta(s)$ which is very similar to $\frac{1}{s-1}$ ?

Comment: the answer is : consider $F(s) = (s-1) \zeta(s)$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and assuming the Riemann hypothesis $\log F(s)$ also is analytic on $Re(s) > 1/2$, hence there is a function $h$ analytic on $Re(s) > 1/2$ such that $F(s) = h(s)^2$

Comment: Truly @user1952009 thanks for your great explanation, as you see yes I have reason to say it , anyway I respect as you say, because I know that sometimes I'm bored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, isn't mine (**is from user1952009**, see the comments below that evidence my mistake) thus don't vote up this answer, please since it is not my merit, and there is a great mistake in my computations, thus subsequent computations were wrong.

Consider $$F(s) = (s-1) \zeta(s)$$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and assuming the **Riemann hypothesis** $$\log F(s)$$ also is analytic on $Re(s) > 1/2$, hence there is a function $h$ analytic  on $Re(s) > 1/2$ such that 
$$F(s) = h(s)^2.$$